# Possible metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-writing

$d_m$ is defined on $\Bbb R^2$  as such:

$d_m(x,y) = max \lbrace|x_1 - y_1| , |x_2 -y_2| \rbrace $ where $x=(x_1,x_2) , y = (y_1 ,y_2)$

Which I have the task of proving whether or not the above s a matric.

I am having some difficultly  with one of the properties of a metric, namely

$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$  the famous triangle inequality.

I have a idea on how this could be proved

I thought of using the elementary properties of the modulus function i.e.:

for $i =1 , 2 $

$|x_i -  y_i| = |x_i -z_i +z_i -y_i|\\
              \leq |x_i -z_i|+|z_i -y_i|$

However , I am unsure how to show that this implies that

$d_m(x,y) \leq d_m(x,z) +d_m(z,y)$

I apologise for my horrible formatting

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry about that. I fixed it

Comment: This suggests the following interesting generalization, which you may want to investigate (I don't know whether it's true or not): If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then $D((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\max\{d(x_1,x_2),d(y_1,y_2)\}$ is a metric on $X^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Note that (using the inequality you already derived in my first inequality)
$$
d(x,y) = \max\{|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|\} \le \max\{|x_1 - z_1| + |z_1-y_1|,|x_2-z_2| + |z_2-y_2|\} \le \max\{|x_1 - z_1|,|x_2-z_2|\} + \max\{|z_1-y_1|,|z_2-y_2|\} = d(x,z) + d(z,y).
$$

Comment: Yes! I corrected it.

Comment: How is $\max\{|x_1 - z_1| + |z_1-y_1|,|x_2-z_2| + |z_2-y_2|\} \le \max\{|x_1 - z_1|,|x_2-z_2|\} + \max\{z_1-y_1|,|z_2-y_2|\}$ ?

Comment: On the left side you choose the maximum between $|x_1 - z_1| + |z_1-y_1|$ and $|x_2-z_2| + |z_2-y_2|$. On the right side you compare the first terms in both expressions and take the highest of those. Similarly you take the highest of the second terms. If you add the two chosen higher terms, then this is bigger than both $|x_1 - z_1| + |z_1-y_1|$ and $|x_2-z_2| + |z_2-y_2|$.

Comment: I am not sure if that is clear?

Comment: Ahh!I see it now